# Instances of SharedPreferences in different SActivites share an inconsistent view of the data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-holo-everywhere

I was using SharedPreferences and everything was working fine.

Then I started tweaking the UI. I added HoloEverywhere as a dependency and extended SActivity instead of Activity. Now none of the SharedPreferences work.

```
mPrefs = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(ctx.getPackageName(),
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
```

This is how I initialized my SP using android's SP at first. I noticed HE also has extended SP so I changed my code to using HE's PreferenceManager and SharedPreferences.

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
```

However, none of my operations are still being saved into SP. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: I mean they look pretty correct to me, I assume you are remembering to call commit on the preference editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the behavior I have observed was indeed unexpected behavior. After [reporting](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/issues/183) it, the author has fixed it. Kudos to him.